# CVS error: connection refused error

Tags: linux, version-control, solaris, cvs

Hi i have installed CVS binary(means created link to binary file) in the path /**home/mrsx/bin** folder and created the respositry in the path **/apps/src/CVSROOT**(CVSROOT respository name).
and added entries in **inetd.conf** as(all in single line):

**cvspserver stream tcp nowait root /home/mrsx/bin/cvs cvs -f --allow-root=/apps/src/CVSROOT  pserver**

and in /etc/services as : **cvspserver      2401/tcp**
and **restarted inetd**.

and set CVSROOT to :pserver:username@servername:2401/apps/src/CVSROOT
and tried to login and i got connection refused error..

can anybody please tell me what is wrong in the above mentioned steps.

Comment: Why do you need a CVS server??? It is obsolete: use `git` or `svn` instead!!

Comment: its a requirnement from client.

Comment: Why don't you install the CVS related packages from your distribution?

Comment: i tried that .. then i got error saying that . c compiler required.. we dont have root access to system.. we need to raise a request for everything.. so i tried binary. can u please tell me the what is wrong in the above steps

Comment: @Sachi Do you also have cvspserver 2401/udp in /etc/services? I don't recall if it is required. Also, I believe 2401 is the default, so something like this should work: cvs -d :pserver:username@servername:/apps/src/CVSROOT login (-d avoids any issues with the CVSROOT environment variable not getting set correctly)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch git/svn/etc. aren't ideal for every situation--for instance they don't lend themselves well to large collections of single-file programs.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem migrating an Ubuntu cvs repository. In the Debian-Ubuntu world, do this:

```
apt-get install cvs xinetd
```

establish your repository ( just follow instructions in the manual)

make sure your users have write permission. Typically create a cvs group, put them in it, and mark the repos 775; chgrp -R cvs *  ( cvs lacks security, read the manual)

add a file in /etc/xinetd.d called  cvspserver

edit the file similar to this:

```
service cvspserver

{

port = 2401

socket_type = stream

protocol = tcp

user = root

wait = no

type = UNLISTED

server = /usr/bin/cvs

server_args = -f --allow-root /usr/local/cvs pserver

disable = no

}
```

reboot or restart xinetd

Comment: I have similar issue CVS error: connection refused error externally from Eclipse Repository Exploring. The answer help to connect via terminal console